# How to count the connected component in the network using networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, connected-components

I'm trying to count the number of connected components (=isolated networks) in the whole network graph, but it takes much more memory and time than I expected.
<strike>I referenced the python code from https://frhyme.github.io/python-libs/nx_algorithm_clique/</strike> and checked the similar question in the stackoverflow ([Find and count the number of isolated and semi-isolated nodes in a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521662/find-and-count-the-number-of-isolated-and-semi-isolated-nodes-in-a-network))

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import clique
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
p = 0.05
G1 = networkx.fast_gnp_random_graph(N, p, seed=32)

print("== nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G1)")
clique_num = 0
for clique in networkx.enumerate_all_cliques(G1):
    # clique type: list
    clique_num+=1
print(f"all cliques count: {clique_num}")
print("=="*30)
```

The network contains about 9,800 nodes and 36,000 edges wtih high sparsity (density=0.1).
I'm sorry for lack of example network, but can anyone suggest other way for counting cliques as below?

[image]

Comment: clique is not the same as isolated network, which one are you interested in?

Comment: Also, you should provide a minimal reproducible example. Either a small sample that you design manually, or code to automate the generation of a larger example if needed.

Comment: @matszwecja I confused the concept of them. Please check the picture that I attached..

Comment: @mozway I added the reproducible example referenced from https://frhyme.github.io/python-libs/nx_clique/

Comment: Yes, those are definitely not cliques (well, 2 is but only because it's a trivial case). You want [connected_components](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html)

Comment: @Ssong in your example (from the [link](https://frhyme.github.io/python-libs/nx_clique/)), all nodes are connected

Comment: @mozway I changed the example and attached the result..

Comment: @matszwecja Thank you for your recommendation! I solved the problem using the code as below:
len([len(c) for c in sorted(networkx.connected_components(G1), key=len, reverse=True)])

Comment: What is wrong with the approach in the linked QA? Try: `list(enumerate(sorted(nx.connected_components(G1), key=len), start=1))` you'll get the numbered sub-graphs

Comment: @mozway Thank you for your comment! Now I can the count the sub-graphs in the original network!

Comment: NB. if you only want to **count** the subgraphs `len(list(nx.connected_components(G1)))` is enough

Comment: @mozway You are right. Thank you for your suggestion!